# Combining cookie and token authentication in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core

I've REST services (Web API) and admin panel (MVC) in one project on ASP.NET Core 2.1. I want to secure my API with JWT token, and my MVC pages with cookies. Can I combinate these two authentication ways. How to configure my Startup.cs, Authorize attribute and sign in functionality.

Comment: Well, that's a general question, but the general answer is yes, of course. You can use the included OWIN scaffodling in VS for MVC. As for your API, there are many ways you can implement `JWT`. I personally (opinion) use `JWT` "bare bones" based on its spec - e.g. [jwtdotnet](https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you should use an OAuth 2.0 framework. please check  [IdentityServer4](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) it enables many features in your applications.

> IdentityServer is middleware that adds the spec compliant OpenID
>   Connect and OAuth 2.0 endpoints to an arbitrary ASP.NET Core
>   application.
>
> Typically, you build (or re-use) an application that contains a login
>   and logout page (and maybe consent - depending on your needs), and the
>   IdentityServer middleware adds the necessary protocol heads to it, so
>   that client applications can talk to it using those standard
>   protocols.

[image: How IdentityServer4 can help]